# React Native Firebase v6 push notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I want to ask how to creat channel in react natibe firebase v6, since the method

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      'local',
      'local notification',
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max,
    );
```

can't use for v6.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@Jscrambler/implementing-react-native-push-notifications-in-android-apps-7e0234dee7b7) tutorial to add push notifications to Android Apps.

To create a notification channel, i add the below 2 lines to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"  
android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>

<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description" 
android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
```

Like as said on the tutorial itself